# 'ls -l' command explanation except of permissions

Tags: linux, command-line-interface

Can anyone please explain 'ls -l' headers ?

```
drwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 16384 Aug  3 07:47 cached/
```

**drwxrwxr-x** this one is explained here: [Explanation of the ls -l command in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811798/explanation-of-the-ls-l-command-in-linux)

can anyone please clarify the rest ?

Comment: I am sure a little googling would give you the answer of this. Also, this question is kind of off-topic here, better in [su] or Unix&Linux.

Comment: I'm googled my soul on it - 3 pages ! :)
Thank you for tips, @fedorqui

Comment: [What do the fields in ls -al output mean?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/103114/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

drwxrwxr-x 1 www-data www-data 16384 Aug  3 07:47 cached/

- Field1: File permission (drwxrwxr-x)
- Field2: Number of links (1)
- Field3: File owner name (www-data)
- Field4: File owner group (www-data)
- Field5: File size in bytes (16834)
- Field6: File's last modified time (Aug 3 07:47)
- Field7: File name (cached)

File permissions:
 - Field1: File type ('-' for file, 'd' for directory, 'l' for link)
 - Fields 2-4: File permission for owner
 - Fields 5-7: File permission for owner group
 - Fields 8-10: File permission for others

r - readable,
w - writable,
e - executable

In your case, drwxrwxr-x

- file type is directory
- read,write and execute access to file owner
- read,write and execute access to file owner group
- read and execute access to others

Comment: this is not an answer, just a link

Comment: The link is now dead. This is why link only answers are not recommended.

Comment: even link doesn't work anymore.